# Derivative of $x \over x+k$?

Tags: calculus

This seems like it should be easy but its got me beat:

$$c = {a \over {a + b} }$$

What is:

$$\partial c \over \partial a$$

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Quotient rule on $\cfrac x{x+k}$
- Product rule on $x(x+k)^{-1}$
- Chain rule on $\left (1+\cfrac kx\right)^{-1}$

Comment: For some embarassing reason I can't explain I thought that because the numerator and denominator shares the $a$ term the Quotient Rule didn't apply.  Sorry.

Answer (score 3):

$a/(a+b)= 1- b/(a+b)$ Thus the derivative is $b(a+b)^-2$